# How will you configure your pom.xml, so that another application bundle will not build again every time you run maven on your application?

Tags: maven, aem, pom.xml

In your application, you have to use another application bundle how will you configure your pom.xml, so that another application bundle will not build again every time you run maven on your application?

Comment: What is an application bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a second maven dependency that gets build everytime you build your application. You ll need to modularize your parent POM and use separate profiles for partial build and full builds.

For example on your parent pom, modules section, include only your application core like this:

```
    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
    </modules>
```

Under profiles, have separate profiles for application build and full build

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>autoInstallPackage</id>
            <modules>
                <module>ui.apps</module>
                <module>ui.content</module>
        </modules>....
        <profile>
        <profile>
            <id>autoInstallWithSecondApplication</id>
            <modules>
                <module>secondapplication</module>
                <module>ui.apps</module>
                <module>ui.content</module>
            </modules>....
        <profile>
```

When you run `mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage`, it will build core, ui.apps, ui.content. When you run `mvn clean install -PautoInstallWithSecondApplication`, it will build core and the dependency project, and then bundles up the deployment package.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily exclude a sub-module as well, by using `-pl '!moduleToExclude'`, this way, for example if you already have the code installed on AEM, you do not need to build it every time.